In Jhipster, how to update the relationship between two entities
enter image description here
I want to change this to oneTomany and I wonder if changing this will also change the restrictions in the database
Tried to change the file however once I changed, many error happened. If there have any jhipster command to change the relationship?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
